# Access specific div using cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am trying to use [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) in order to access one string of characters that is within a `div` in HTML.

This is what the `div` looks like on the website:

```
<div class="_6wae">Only 5 Hours Left/div>
```

I have tried accessing the `div` using this code here:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(html);
const info = $('._6wae');
console.log(info.text());
```

When I run the JS it seems to work halfway... I get an empty line on the console where the text should be.

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: Can you please share the HTML that you are parsing using `cheerio`?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/donate/2486339634914015/ Here is the facebook post I am trying to parse through. I'm trying to find how many days left until the fundraiser is complete.

Comment: be sure that inside your html file you have that div. It may be created on the fly via javascript. You need to fetch it from selenium + chromedriver or another scraping solution.

Comment: Upon inspecting the page using Chrome Inspector it seems that it is in fact within HTML. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Yes running `curl -vs https://www.facebook.com/donate/2486339634914015/` confirms this theory.

Comment: @HunterCasillas Found the culprit, see answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Facebook returns different payloads depending on the user agent header.

Try the following:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.facebook.com/donate/2486339634914015/',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  var element = $('._6wae');
  console.log(element.text());
});
```

Although the above works, it’s probably an ephemeral solutions as it’s possible Facebook changes the `_6wae` class frequently.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made the suggested changes and it fixed my issue :)

Comment: Always a pleasure. Happy hacking!